# 404 error page getting rendered in Rails application even if the entity exists in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written one Ruby on Rails application. Here I have used one model Student. Problem is that while trying to render page of a particular student by students_controller, it keeps giving 404 not found though the student exists in the db. I am running my application in staging mode. show in students_controller is as follows:

```
def show
  @student = Student.get(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
  format.json {render :json => @student}
end
```

In my staging.rb I have following line only when I think this 404 error page can be rendered.

```
 config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

And in routes.rb I have added the following line:

```
 unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'
 end
```

In log I can see that show page is getting rendered but immediately after this error_404 page is getting rendered. And this show page is getting rendered perfectly for every other students. I don't have any clue about how to fix this bug.

Comment: Posting your `code` would be very helpful!

Comment: We can't help without the exact error message you are getting. Can you post a relevant sample of the log?

Comment: Why you are using **`get`** here `@student = Student.get(params[:id])`.It should be `@student = Student.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: @Pavan, if this is the issue then how it is working for every other students? I have modified my question by adding some code. I think it will help.

Comment: `get` is not defined by default on an AR model. If it's something you've written, you need to explain it.

Comment: I am using DataMapper not ActiveRecord.

Comment: Try using with `find` as i suggested and let me know.

Comment: Well,you should be adding that in the question to make it clear!

Comment: Can you add the logs to the question?

Comment: What's this: `Student.get(params[:id])`

Comment: In datamapper we can get one student record with this statement Student.get(id).

Comment: @Pavan, find statement is not working as syntax is little bit different for Datamapper than Activerecord.

Comment: I guess your format.json statement only slipped outside of the respond_to block when you copied the code to stackoverflow, right? Otherwise, that would be one error I see in your code. Then, it is unclear what happens within your template. You might have additional find statements there which throw the NotFound-Exceptions. You should compare what happens when 1. requesting the student in question via rails console 2. requesting with json format 3 requesting with html format. Than come back here and we see if we can help